# Limit without l'hospital,derivatives,taylor series...just using limit properties and some basic limits

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

As the title says i have to solve this two limits without the help of these,i only know some basic limits from 1st semester calculus:

1st limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\ln(2x^2-1)}$$

And the 2nd limit:

$$\lim_{x\to -2}(2\sqrt{-x-1}-1)^{1/(4^{-x}-16)}$$

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Edit:
First one i changed a little into:
$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin{\pi x}(2x^2-2)x}{\ln(2x^2-1)(2x^2-2)x}$
but i encountered a problem,while i still get a 0 at the bottom and it doesn't help 
I know the result for first limit if it helps: $-\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: Will edit a little

Comment: You question may be in danger of being closed I'm afraid.

Comment: But i got stuck at $\pi \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x}{2x^2-2}$

Comment: The numerator while approching $1$ is non-zero while the denomintator is, what do you conlcude?

Comment: I don't know where you going with that i made a mistake i think,i can't use a basic limit when x goes to 1, it had to go to 0. I made a mistake. I'm again at the start.

Comment: L'Hospitalet? I didn't know that L'Hôpital was from Barcelona!

Comment: **L'Hôpital** or **L'Hopital** or **L'Hospital** please.

Comment: Well sorry for not learning it yet and not knowing the correct way to write it. And i am not even a native english speaker, so you shouldn't pick on my english skills.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider $$A=\frac{\sin({\pi x})}{\log(2x^2-1)}$$ and make a change of veriable $x=y+1$. So, after minor rearrangements and simplifications, $$A=\frac{\sin{(\pi (y+1))}}{\log(2(y+1)^2-1)}=-\frac{\sin (\pi  y)}{\log (1+2 y (y+2))}$$ Now, you know that, for small values of $z$, $\sin(z)\approx z$ and that $\log(1+z)\approx z$. So replacing each time $z$ by its appropriate value ($\pi y$ for the numerator) and $2y(y+2)$ for the denominator, we have $$A\approx -\frac{\pi y}{2y(y+2)}=-\frac{\pi}{2(y+2)} $$ and $y$ is going to $0$. So, as a final result$$\lim_{y\to 0} A=-\frac{\pi}4$$

For the second one $$B=(2\sqrt{-x-1}-1)^{\frac{1}{4^{-x}-16}}$$ make a change of veriable $x=y-2$; this makes $$B=\left(2 \sqrt{1-y}-1\right)^{\frac{1}{4^{2-y}-16}}$$ So, $$\log(B)={\frac{1}{4^{2-y}-16}}\log\left(2 \sqrt{1-y}-1\right)$$ Using the same trick as before $$\log\left(2 \sqrt{1-y}-1\right)\approx \log(1-y)\approx -y$$ since $\sqrt{1+z}\approx \frac z 2$. Now consider $${4^{2-y}-16}=16(4^{-y}-1)=16(e^{-y \log(4)}-1)$$ and you know thet close to $0$, $e^{az}\approx 1+az$ which makes $$16(e^{-y \log(4)}-1)\approx -16 y\log(4)$$  All of that makes $$\log(B)\approx \frac y {16 y\log(4)}=\frac 1 {16 \log(4)}$$ and then $$B\approx e^{\frac{1}{16 \log (4)}}$$

Comment: Yep. I always take my limits straight, letting them go to zero.

Comment: "for small values of z, sin(z)≈z and that log(1+z)≈z." How do we know that without derivatives?

Comment: That's what i'm thinking right now...

Comment: @zhw.  Just observation : plot the function $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=x$, $y=\log(1+x)$ and $y=x$ on the same plot for $0< x<0.1$ and conclude.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici You mean all that time we spend in calculus proving things like $\sin x/x \to 1$ could be be better spent just drawing pictures?

Comment: @zhw. No, indeed ! But remember that science is also based on observation.

Comment: How do you *observe* $\sin x/x \to 1$?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  we have to change the limit in that way that we can just input x to which it goes, or we use those basic limits. We haven't used this method with observing for small values. And i don't know if we can use this. And everything we do in the solution, has to be backed up by a proof or theorem. And i think we didn't have a theorem like that yet..so that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you know that

$$\lim_{u\to0}{\sin u\over u}=1\quad\text{and}\quad \lim_{u\to0}{\ln u\over u-1}=1$$

Then the key to the first limit is to use the general theorem

$$\lim_{x\to c}{f(x)\over g(x)}={\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\over\lim_{x\to c}g(x)}$$

(provided $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)\not=0$) applied to

$$f(x)={\sin\pi x\over x-1}\quad\text{and}\quad g(x)={\ln(2x^2-1)\over x-1}$$

Using the trig identity $\sin(\pi x-\pi)=-\sin\pi x$, we see that

$$\lim_{x\to1}{\sin\pi x\over x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}{-\pi\sin\pi(x-1)\over\pi(x-1)}=-\pi\lim_{u\to0}{\sin u\over u}=-\pi$$

Using the related general theorem $\lim_{x\to c}(f(x)g(x))=\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$, we see that

$$\lim_{x\to1}{\ln(2x^2-1)\over x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\left({\ln(2x^2-1)\over(2x^2-1)-1}\cdot{(2x^2-1)-1\over x-1}\right)=\lim_{u\to0}{\ln u\over u-1}\cdot\lim_{x\to1}2(x+1)=4$$

Putting these together gives $-\pi/4$ for the first limit.

Something similar should work for the second limit (after first taking the logarithm).  The trick is to identify the basic limits you're allowed to assume, and then tease things apart algebraically, using general theorems about limits.

Comment: I got one question,u multiplied both numerator and denumerator by $\frac{1}{x-1}$ or am i mistaken  @Barry Cipra

Comment: And where to apply logarithm in the 2nd,i

Comment: @user246608, yes, I multiplied numerator and denominator by $1/(x-1)$.  As for the second limit, it's a standard trick, with expressions like this, to take the logarithm, *then* take the limit, and then, at the end, exponentiate this limit to get the limit of the original function.  See what Claude Leibovici did in his answer, going from $B$ to $\log(B)$ and back again.

Comment: Yeah i got it now